# While displaying its also print old Data from local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage, input-field

```
  function addrow() {
            debugger;
            var person = [];
            if (localStorage.person1 != null && localStorage.person1 !=undefined) {
                var person = JSON.parse(localStorage.person1);


            }

            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
            person.push({ 
                pname: name,
                pcity: city
            });


            localStorage.setItem('person1', JSON.stringify(person));
            bind();
        }

    function bind() {
        debugger;
        var per_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person1'));
        for (i = 0; i < per_list.length; i++ ) {
                var table = document.getElementById('ptable');
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
            col1.innerHTML = per_list[i].pname;
            col2.innerHTML = per_list[i].pcity;
            }

        }
```

I have two fields `name` and `city`;Now, click on "add row" prints `ok` for first `value`, but afterwards it is printing both `old` and `new` value.. And, i want only new entry below the `old` input.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the table since you are showing all the elements in the `.bind` function.

```
function bind() {
  debugger;
  var per_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person1'));
  // clear the table
  var table = document.getElementById('ptable');
  for (var i = 0, rows = table.rows.length; i < rows; i++) {
    table.deleteRow(0)
  }
  // fill the table
  for (i = 0; i < per_list.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
    col1.innerHTML = per_list[i].pname;
    col2.innerHTML = per_list[i].pcity;
  }
}
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gabriele-petrioli if i want the printed data as it is after refreshing page what shoud i do?

Comment: @Tushar just call `bind()` once the page is loaded. (but change the code in bind at the beginning to `var per_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('person1')) || [];`) (*added the `|| []` at the end of the line so that if the `person1` is not yet defined it should just consider it empty*)

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/128165/gabriele-petrioli ,i tried and call the function at the starting of program but its not work please suggest proper placement of it

Comment: @Tushar I would need to know more about your page setup.. But try adding `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bind);` right after the definition of the `bind` function (*outisde of it*).